# Get a selected radio button value after POST to set other fields enabled/disabled

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application with a simple control to all selection of All Dates or selecting a Date Range.

The radio buttons have an onclick handler to enable/disable the dat pickers. All work well so far.

When I try to set the correct context state for the datepickers after doing a POST I cannot get the jQuery selector to return the radio buttons checked value.

The code is as follows:

```
   <%= Html.RadioButton("DateSelection.AllDates", "AllDates", Model.AllDates == "AllDates", new { onclick = "setReadOnly(this);" })%>ALL Dates&nbsp;
        <%= Html.RadioButton("DateSelection.AllDates", "Selection", Model.AllDates == "Selection", new { onclick = "setReadOnly(this);" })%>Selection
        <%= Html.DatePicker("DateSelection.startdate", Model.StartDate, "", "") %>
        &nbsp;To&nbsp;<%= Html.DatePicker("DateSelection.enddate", Model.EndDate, "", "") %><br />
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/jscript" >
function setReadOnly(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "Selection") {
        $('#DateSelection_startdate').css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff')
            .removeAttr('readonly')
            .datepicker('enable');
        $('#DateSelection_enddate').css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff')
            .removeAttr('readonly')
            .datepicker('enable');
    }
    else {
        $('#DateSelection_startdate').css('backgroundColor', '#eeeeee')
            .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
            .val('')
            .datepicker('disable');
        $('#DateSelection_enddate').css('backgroundColor', '#eeeeee')
            .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
            .val('')
            .datepicker('disable');
    }
}
```

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#DateSelection_startdate').datepicker('disable').css('backgroundColor', '#eeeeee')
            .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
            .val('');
    $('#DateSelection_enddate').datepicker('disable').css('backgroundColor', '#eeeeee')
            .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
            .val('');
    var selected = $('#DateSelection_AllDates:checked');
    setReadOnly(selected);
});
```

The javascript line that is causing the problem is

```
var selected = $('#DateSelection_AllDates:checked');
```

which will NOT return the checked radio button.

Using

```
var selected = $('#DateSelection_AllDates');
```

will return the first radio button value as expected i.e. applying the ':checked' filter ALWAYS returns undefined.

Can anyone see anything wrong here?

Comment: Any chance that you have more than one element on the page with `DateSelection_AllDates` as the ID? If so, this could throw things off.

Comment: No, the DateSelection_AllDates is simply a RadioButton group of two readiobuttons.

Comment: patrick, you were on the right track with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something more like this:

```
$("input[name='DateSelection_AllDates']:checked")
```

Hard to tell without seeing your generated HTML, since I don't know MVC.  Clearly you have multiple radio buttons with the same NAME (hence a group, yes?).  This is not the same as an ID, which by definition must be unique.

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Yes, that was the issue and thank you also 'patrick' above. MVC auto creates the ID and I give the name.
There were two issues then. The main one was that I was using the ID which was of course duplicated. Secondly I changed the enclosure to var selected = $("input[name='DateSelection.AllDates']:checked").val();
and as you can see passed the val() through to the function and checked for it explicitly as follows if (obj.value == "Selection" || obj == "Selection") {
Many thanks